# To check if there are any a and b that satisfy the given equation

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, c++17, c++14

> **Problem**
> You are given a positive integer X. Your task is to tell whether there exist two positive integers a and b (a > 0, b > 0) such that
> 2⋅a+2⋅b+a⋅b=X
> If there exist positive integers a and b satisfying the above condition print YES, otherwise print NO.
>
> **Input Format**
> The first line of input will contain a single integer T, denoting the number of test cases.
> Each test case consists of a single line containing a positive integer X.
>
> **Output Format**
> For each test case, output on a new line YES or NO.
>
> You may print each character of the string in either uppercase or lowercase (for example, the strings yes, YES, Yes, and yeS will all be treated as identical).

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t,x,i,j;

    cin>>t;

    while(t--)
    { 
    
       cin>>x; 
   
       for(i=1; i<x; i++)
       {
           for(j=1; j<x; j++)
           {
               if(2*i + 2*j + i*j == x)
               {
                   cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
               }
               else
               {
                   cout<<"No"<<endl;
               } 
           }
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

According to my above code, I will get No for every iteration of if_loop and Yes for that one specific case for which it satisfies that equation, but I want it to print yes or no only once. Please tell me how it can be done.

Comment: Move the code with the loops to a function. If you find a match print "Yes" and return, and print "No" after the loops.

Comment: BTW, once you fix `i`, possible `j` is only `X - ((2 * i) / (2+i))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a flag variable and set to true if consition is satisfied.Print it after the loop not inside the loop

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int t,x,i,j;
  int flag;

  cin>>t;

  while(t--)
  { 
     cin>>x; 
 
     flag = checkSatisfiedNumber(x)
     if (flag == 1)
      cout<<"Yes"<<endl;
     else
      cout<<"No"<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}

int checkSatisfiedNumber(int x){
int i,j;
 for(i=1; i<x; i++)
     {
         for(j=1; j<x; j++)
         {
             if(2*i + 2*j + i*j == x)
             {
                 return 1;
             }
         }
     }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: In a nested loop `break` only breaks out of the inner loop, not the outer. Easier and IMO more readable to move the code to a function and return early.

Comment: Your `flag` is unneeded.

Comment: Use `bool` for boolean values. A function that returns an `int` should conceptually return a number, not a boolean flag.

Comment: @JaMiT, thanks for suggestions,its just a normal approach to define why you are getting issue. You can optimise it more.

Comment: It would be a good idea to try and compile the code after modifications. Move the function above main or provide a prototype and declare `i` and `j`.

Comment: @Manik,please upvote it and accept it if you find it suitable

Comment: @Manik Thanks for the help, i accepted the answer but can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation yet